# Convergence of an infinite series question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I determine which values of x for which the series x - $x^3$ + $x^5$ - $x^7$ + $x^9$... converges? What is the sum of the series for those values of x?

Comment: Do you know what geometric series is?

Comment: If a series $\sum_n a_n$ converges, there is a basic condition that $a_n$ must satisfy. What is that condition? That will tell you something about $x$.

Comment: Yes, I do. I was thinking that the series would converge if |r|<1 and r is -$x^2$ in this case. So x would be in (-1,1), however, then I am not sure of the sum of the series for those values of x.

Comment: What is the sum of $1+r+r^2+\cdots + r^n$?

Comment: would it be  = 1/(1-r) ?

Comment: Well, that is the limit as $n \to \infty$, but that is good enough. If $r=x^2$ what would the formula give? And then note that the above is $x(1-x^2+x^4-x^6...)$.

Comment: would it give x/(1 + $x^2$)? Sorry, I am not very good at these problems.

Comment: Yes. I meant $r=-x^2$ above. It takes practice. The geometric series appears again and again throughout mathematics, so after five decades it drills itself into your brain :-).

Answer (score 0):

This is a rephrasing of the comments section.

Because this is an infinite geometric series, $|r^2|<1$. The common ratio is $-x^2$ (pick any two consecutive terms: say $x$ and $-x^3$), so $x^4<1$ which gives $-1 < x < 1$.

The sum of an infinite geometric series is $\frac{a}{1-r}$. Substituting $r = -x^2$, and the first term ($a$) which is equal to $x$, gives the sum of the series as $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$.